# List Multiplication to dataframe

Tags: list, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, transpose, numpy-ndarray

List = [1, 2, 3]

Final out put need create a data frame like this:

1 2 3

2 4 6

3 6 9

I have tried to create list using below code but i need a data frame::

```
List = [1,2,3]
New_list=[]
for i in List:
   for j in List:
      New_list.append(i*j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
l = [1,2,3]
ln = np.array(l)[np.newaxis]
pd.DataFrame(ln*ln.T)
```

Comment: I have used the same. Thanks